# Errors Installing Scrapy with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, pip

I have a new mac which has Python 2.7 installed in `/usr/bin/python`
I have installed python3 in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3`

I then installed pip in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pip`

When I try and install scrapy using `pip install scrapy` I get the below error.

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/b_/tp7wz2y10c3b3d9k_x1ddxr80000gn/T/pip-install-1x65b25b/Twisted/
```

Basically I think this is related to having two different python versions but would like some clarification on this issue??

Comment: what was your command line when trying to install pip? it should work with `pip3 install scrapy`

Comment: Please post the complete error log.

Comment: I was prompted to install Developer Tools , after which I used pip3 install scrape and it worked . Thanks d_kennetz .